# .NET 5 BackgroundService in Kubernetes Doesn't Exit

Tags: c#, .net, docker, kubernetes, background-service

I'm able to successfully run a .NET 5 Console Application with a `BackgroundService` in an Azure Kubernetes cluster on Ubuntu 18.04. In fact, the `BackgroundService` is all that really runs: just grabs messages from a queue, executes some actions, then terminates when Kubernetes tells it to stop, or the occasional exception.

It's this last scenario which is giving me problems. When the `BackgroundService` hits an unrecoverable exception, I'd like the container to stop (complete, or whatever state will cause Kubernetes to either restart or destroy/recreate the container).

Unfortunately, any time an exception is encountered, the `BackgroundService` *appears* to hit the `StopAsync()` function (from what I can see in the logs and console output), but the container stays in a running state and never restarts. My Main() is as appears below:

```
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Build service host and execute.
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .UseConsoleLifetime()
                .Build();

            // Attach application event handlers.
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += OnProcessExit;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Beginning WebSec.Scanner.");
                await host.StartAsync();
                await host.WaitForShutdownAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("WebSec.Scanner has completed.");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up...");

                // Ensure host is properly disposed.
                if (host is IAsyncDisposable ad)
                {
                    await ad.DisposeAsync();
                }
                else if (host is IDisposable d)
                {
                    d.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

If relevant, those event handlers for `ProcessExit` and `UnhandledException` exist to flush the AppInsights telemetry channel (maybe that's blocking it?):

```
        private static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Ensure AppInsights logs are submitted upstream.
            Console.WriteLine("Flushing logs to AppInsights");
            TelemetryChannel.Flush();
        }

        private static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            var thrownException = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
            Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception thrown: {0}", thrownException.Message);

            // Ensure AppInsights logs are submitted upstream.
            Console.WriteLine("Flushing logs to AppInsights");
            TelemetryChannel.Flush();
        }
```

I am only overriding `ExecuteAsync()` in the `BackgroundService`:

```
        protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation(
                "Service started.");

            try
            {
                // Loop until the service is terminated.
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // Do some work...
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.logger.LogWarning(
                    ex,
                    "Terminating due to exception.");
            }

            this.logger.LogInformation(
                "Service ending.",
        }
```

My Dockerfile is simple and has this line to run the service:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyService.dll"]
```

Am I missing something obvious? I feel like there's something about running this as a Linux container that I'm forgetting in order to make this run properly.

Thank you!

Comment: This is by design - imagine an application that has 3 services registered - one of them stopping might be completely fine. Fix is to inject an [IHostApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and call `StopApplication` in your exception handler.

Comment: @RB. makes a lot of sense. I was thinking somehow the framework knew if all `BackgroundService` processes had terminated and would just know to end the application. I need to see if I encounter an exception to confirm this works but it seems this would be the likely culprit. Thank you!

Comment: @RB. sorry, did you mean calling it in the try/catch block in the `BackgroundService`, or in the `UnhandledException` handler? It does not appear to be working in the try/catch block, nor if I just put it after the try/catch block (which does get hit if an exception is thrown - I see log output which is written just before the call to `StopApplication()`.

Comment: I meant calling it in the `catch` block, yes. I've added a full worked example to explain myself - hope that clears up any confusion :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full example of how to use `IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()`.

```
void Main()
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
        })
        .Build();
    
    Console.WriteLine("Starting service");

    host.Run();
    
    Console.WriteLine("Ended service");
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

public class MyService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _lifetime;
    
    private readonly Random _rnd = new Random();
    
    public MyService(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        _lifetime = lifetime;
    }
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                
                var nextNumber = _rnd.Next(10);
                if (nextNumber < 8)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"We have number {nextNumber}");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Number too high");
                }
                
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
        // If the application is shutting down, ignore it
        catch (OperationCanceledException e) when (e.CancellationToken == stoppingToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Application is shutting itself down");
        }
        // Otherwise, we have a real exception, so must ask the application
        // to shut itself down.
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oh dear. We have an exception. Let's end the process.");
            // Signal to the OS that this was an error condition by 
            // setting the exit code.
            Environment.ExitCode = 1;
            _lifetime.StopApplication();
        }
    }
}
```

Typical output from this program will look like:

```
Starting service
We have number 0
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\rowla\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad6\_spgznchd\shadow-1
We have number 2
Oh dear. We have an exception. Let's end the process.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
Ended service
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post and it wasn't obvious to me that RB's answer above would have solved my problem, so just wanted to expand on his answer in case it may help others. I'm using .net7 and .net8 in kubernetes and had two issues, 1) my background service would not exit, and 2) if an error was thrown, the process would exit with code 0 indicating a success to kubernetes.

After lots of research and testing, you'll want to inject `IHostApplicationLifetime` and stop your application because a background service will run until cancelled. Catch exceptions and set the `Environment.ExitCode = 1` to let kubernetes know there was a failure.

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try
    {
        // your long-running work
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // log or ignore
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // BackgroundService always exits with code 0 which does not let kubernetes know
        // if there was an error. Explicitly setting exit code to 1 to relay a failure.
        Environment.ExitCode = 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        _lifetime.StopApplication();
    }
}
```